# How make data type generics in Swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

```
struct BaseResponse<T:Decodable>: Decodable {
    var code : Int
    var status : String
    var message : String
    var data : T?
}
```

Here is my base response class.

Some time response came in arrays with multiple object and some time came in dictionary in "data" key.

I want to make the data key dynamic to accept both array and  dictionaries  currently it accept dictionary only.

Is it possible to make dynamic?

Comment: If you know exactly **when** `data` comes as dictionary or array you can use generics. If not you can't.

Comment: Do you need it as dic or array at the end of the day ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct BaseResponse<T:Decodable>: Decodable {
    var code : Int
    var status : String
    var message : String
    var data : T?
    var datas: [T]?
}
```

My Project
[image]

Comment: the data key is always same in both cases . How can i make data dynamic

Comment: This makes no sense. `T` can represent both a single item and an array.

Comment: T can't represent an array.

Comment: Believe me, it can.

Comment: Really? I hope to learn this method and improve my program. Thank you so much.